# How to read only part of a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, string, data-manipulation

I am pulling in a string from another web page. I want to read that string into a variable but only after a certain point. Eg:

```
#stringexample

var variable;
```

I want variable to equal stringexample but not contain the # how could I do this?

This is how I am using the variable at the moment.

```
$("#Outputajax").load("folder/"+ variable +".html");
```

This is the way that works but isn't a variable.

```
$("#Outputajax").load("folder/webpage.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to trim of the first character, then you can use substring...

```
var input = "#stringexample";
input = input.substring(1);
//input = "stringexample"
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/4mxJf/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var myVariable = stringExample.replace('#','');
```

Comment: Elaborate man! This is the second question from you today to pop up in the review queue that I don't have a delete reason for.

Comment: Sorry man. I guess I'm brief because I don't wanna do people's homework for them. They learn more with factual syntax that they can go work into their code and grow from. That said, I'll make an effort to be more descriptive moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Could just use `variable.substr(1)` to cut off the first character.

If you want to specifically remove the hash from the start (but do nothing if the hash isn't there), try `variable.replace(/^#/,"")`

Comment: Still to this day do not understand the use of substr when substring is understood by all browsers since the dawn of time

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to get everything in the string AFTER the hashtag. The other solutions will leave anything ahead of the hashtag in as well. And substring does not work if the hashtag is not the first symbol.

```
variable= "#stringexample".split("#")[1];
```

This splits the string into an array of strings, with the parameter as the point where to split, without including the parameter itself. There will be an empty string as the first parameter, and everything after the hashtag is the second string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var slicer = function(somestring){
   var parsedString = somestring;
   parsedString = parsedString.slice(1);
   return parsedString
}

// run from yors function with some string
var someYouVar = slicer("#something")
```

Comment: complicated waste of time

Comment: @mplungjan , i know, write function just for slice first simbol, not wery good idea) but topic starter can't google for slice or substr,so i'l try to give him solution

Comment: But the excessive declaration of strings that needs to be garbage collected is just silly when "#something".slice(1) will do all you spent a function on

Comment: @mplungjan ok it was bad example. maybe someone will read it, and DON'T repeat such stupid thing)